# Database backup SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How to take backup of SQL Server 2008 system to local client system?

Please give procedure

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically, if so, on what language/platform?

Comment: You **cannot** backup a SQL Server to your local directory directly - you need to put the backup onto a drive connected to the SQL Server machine, and then copy it.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) will give you a guide as to what options/parameters are available for backing up your database.

And this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304.aspx) will tell you what you need to do.  Example A shows you how to back up to a drive and directory.

Comment: OK. but i want how to take backup server to client system directly

Comment: Copy it to a network drive where both machines have access to. Then, copy to your local client from the network drive.  Then you can do a restore from there.

Comment: @saran: you **CANNOT** do a backup from a SQL Server directly to your local workstation - it just **CANNOT** be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done in this way:

- Pre: There is SQL Server installed somewhere in company (SQL1)

  1. Install SQL Server Express on your local machine (SQL2)
  2. Install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Express on your local machine
  3. Start SSMS and connect to SQL1 and check the structure
  4. Start SSMS and connect to SQL2 and create same structure
  5. Start Importing Tool, select SQL1 as source and SQL2 as destination and import all data you need
  6. Now you can make an update of your local SQL Server (SQL2)
  7. Finished

Perhaps this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it's awkward and you might not have the permissions you need to do it anyway. In most environments, it's a lot easier to do what others have suggested: make a backup on the server itself or to a file server, then copy the file from that location to your workstation.

But if you absolutely have to do it and if you have the right permissions (and network access) then you can do it as follows:

1. Create a share on your local workstation
2. Give the necessary share and/or NTFS permissions to the MSSQL service account
3. Use the BACKUP command with the UNC path to the share

More details about permissions and backing up to UNC paths are in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179313%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).